# SSH password not working from iPhone to laptop

Tags: iphone, ssh, passwords

I recently jailbroke my iPhone 4, running iOS 5.1, and am trying to recover some files that were deleted. I am new to SSH and am currently using Cygwin.

The issue I'm having is that when I try to to `ssh <username>@<my laptop's IP address>` from Mobile Terminal on my iPhone, I get:

> Permission denied (public key, password, keyboard-interactive)

I'm confused. The password is right, but it's saying that I'm wrong.

I know a lot of people say to use something called keys to avoid password login, but I'd rather just stick with password login, seeing as how I won't be doing this very often, probably just this once to grab raw iPhone data (using dd commands).

On my iPhone Mobile Terminal, the first thing I type is "su" then enter my password, then am presented with `FirstName-LastNames-iPhone:/var/mobile root#`.

Then I proceed to type `ssh <username>@(laptop's ip address)`

It goes through and asks for a password, and that's where it all goes to hell. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using PuTTy to connect and see what's going on?

Comment: Not really a programming question - I've nominated it for migration to SuperUser.

Comment: You need to enable password access in SSH on Cygwin. There are many, many walkthroughs on Google to see how that is done.